# CWebUser and CUserIdentity

Tags: yii

I'm building an authentication module for my application and I don't quite understand the relation between `CWebUser` and `CUserIdentity`.

To set the user id to `Yii::app()->user->id` I have to do that in my `UserIdentity` class and create a method:

```
public function getId() {
    return $this->_id;
}
```

But to set `isAdmin` to `Yii::app()->user->isAdmin` I have to create a method in my `WebUser` class:

```
function getIsAdmin() {
    $user = $this->loadUser(Yii::app()->user->id);
    return intval($user->user_level_id) == AccountModule::USER_LEVEL_ADMIN;
}
```

Why can't I just create the methods the `UserIdentity` class? What is the division of labour here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `UserIdentity` (UI) class is like an ID card, where as the `WebUser` class is the actual person plus everything you know about them.

The UI class gives you authentication via database, webservices, textfile, whatever. It lets you know what the key attributes are and allows you to manipulate them. The user however can give you more information about what they're allowed to do, there names, granular permissions and such.

### OK, end metaphor

The UI class holds the key information, so when asking for the users ID it will refer to the User *Identity* class to get the *Identifier* for the user.

Anything that isn't related to identifying or authenticating a user is in the `WebUser` class

Clear it up at all?

### Your example

You gave the `getId` function as an example, but that can be created on `WebUser` to override the default, which is to pull from the state.

So not sure what you mean here.

Comment: That's perfect thank you, I will overwrite the `getId` in `WebUser` so that everything is in one spot. Thanks!

Comment: @Paystey: What do you mean by "pull from the state"? What state? I wish to overwrite webuser to get the ID instead.

Comment: "state" being a database entry, session data runtime config etc. so you can return the actual ID of the user. The default is a Yii default to identify `User Identities`. I'll update my answer if that makes sense?

Answer (score 2):

I like how the accepted answer used real life examples to make it easier to understand. However, I also like how Chris explained it [here](http://chris-backhouse.com/Cook-your-own-User-Authentication-in-Yii-%E2%80%93-Part-1/989) with example.

> User information is stored in an instance of the CWebUser class and
>   this is created on application initialisation (ie: when the User first
>   connects with the website), irrespective of whether the user is logged
>   in or not. By default, the user is set to “ Guest”.  Authentication is
>   managed by a class called CUserIdentity and this class checks that the
>   user is known and a valid user. How this validation occurs will depend
>   on your application, perhaps against a database, or login with
>   facebook, or against an ldap server etc...

Answer (score 2):

And what is the benefit of using all those classes? I can do everything just by User model. If I set scenario "login", password will be checked during validation. If validation is OK, I can set to session my own variable like this:

```
$model = new User("login");
$model->attributes = $_POST["User"];
if ($model->validate())
{
  Yii::app()->session["currentUser"] = $model;
}
else
{
  // .. show error
  unset(Yii::app()->session["currentUser"]);
}
```

In User model I have then static methods to check this variable

```
public static function isGuest()
{
  return isset(Yii::app()->session["currentUser"]);
}

public static function getCurrent()
{
  return Yii::app()->session["currentUser"];
}
```

And I can call it very shortly:

```
User::isGuest();
$model = User::getCurrent();
// instead of writing this:
Yii::app()->user->isGuest;
```

So why should I use so complicated hierarchy of classes that is suggested by Yii? I never understood it.